# Retrieve value from a map with a regex key

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am trying to get a value from the map based on a regex key:

```
const nameMapping = new Map([
  ['Name1', 'This is some name'],
  ['Name1_2', 'This is another name'],
  [/^[A]{1}[0]{2}/, 'Name from regex']
])

console.log(nameMapping.get('Name1'))
console.log(nameMapping.get('Name1_2'))
console.log(nameMapping.get('A0012'))  // prints undefined
```

Basically, if the key starts with `A00`, then it should return `Name from regex` string.

With this example:

```
console.log(nameMapping.get('A0012'))
```

How can I make it print `Name from regex`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only have either strings or regexes as the keys of the map, you can write a custom function as below to first find the matching key, and then get its value.

```
function getValue(map, keyToGet) {
    for (let key of nameMapping.keys()) {
    let isMatching = (typeof key === 'string') ? (key === keyToGet) : key.test(keyToGet);
        if (isMatching) {
            return map.get(key);
        }
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Then you can use that function to get your values.

```
console.log(getValue(nameMapping, 'Name1'))
console.log(getValue(nameMapping, 'Name1_2'))
console.log(getValue(nameMapping, 'A0012'))
```